# JQuery change selected="true" on select - angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this select on my page:

```
<select id="myselect">
      <option value="car" selected="true">Car</option>
      <option value="bike">Bike</option>
      <option value="plane">Plane</option>
</select>
```

I need the selected option to be bike ... how do I change it using jQuery?

I've tried:

```
$("#myselect option:selected").val('bike');
```

and

```
$("#myselect").val('bike');
```

But they don't work

Comment: [Works fine here](http://jsbin.com/niyoje/1/edit?html,js,output). Voting to close, I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: `true` is not an acceptable value for the `selected` attribute, the only value you can give it is `selected`. Use a validator: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: `$("#myselect").val('bike');` is the correct way and should work.

Comment: Strange...the problem must be in that the select box is in an angularjs page

Comment: Make sure you have added this line in $(document).ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a dummy button to change the `selected` on click of it. Here is the code

HTML

```
<select id="myselect">
      <option value="car" selected="true">Car</option>
      <option value="bike">Bike</option>
      <option value="plane">Plane</option>
</select>
<button id="cS">
 Change Selected
</button>
```

JS

```
$("#cS").on('click',function(){
$('#myselect option[value="bike"]').attr('selected',true)

})
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/z1495A2ZBZ71dzVtzfUm?p=preview)